# TYPO3 7.6 - cooluri redirects everything to root page

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

Like the headline says, I installed cooluri and each link redirects to the root page. But the URL is rewritten correctly!

e.g. '/index.php?id=4' is rewritten to '/Products', but the Page shown is the root page which should be just '/'

my /typo3/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Enable URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Store the current location in an environment variable CWD to use
# mod_rewrite in .htaccess files without knowing the RewriteBase
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=CWD:%2]

# Rules to set ApplicationContext based on hostname
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.example\.com$
#RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Development]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging\.example\.com$
#RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Production/Staging]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
#RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Production]

# Rule for versioned static files, configured through:
# - $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['versionNumberInFilename']
# - $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['versionNumberInFilename']
# IMPORTANT: This rule has to be the very first RewriteCond in order to work!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ %{ENV:CWD}$1.$3 [L]

# Access block for folders
RewriteRule _(?:recycler|temp)_/ - [F]
RewriteRule fileadmin/templates/.*\.(?:txt|ts)$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^(?:vendor|typo3_src|typo3temp/logs) - [F]
RewriteRule (?:typo3conf/ext|typo3/sysext|typo3/ext)/[^/]+/(?:Configuration|Resources/Private|Tests?|Documentation|docs?)/ - [F]

# Block access to all hidden files and directories with the exception of
# the visible content from within the `/.well-known/` hidden directory (RFC 5785).
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!(^|/)\.well-known/([^./]+./?)+$" [NC]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (?:^|/)\. - [F]

# Stop rewrite processing, if we are in the typo3/ directory or any other known directory
# NOTE: Add your additional local storages here
RewriteRule ^(?:typo3/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]

# If the file/symlink/directory does not exist => Redirect to index.php.
# For httpd.conf, you need to prefix each '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' with '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php [QSA,L]
```

my root TS:

```
config {
  simulateStaticDocuments = 1
  simulateStaticDocuments_noTypeIfNoTitle = 1
  tx_cooluri_enable = 1
  redirectOldLinksToNew = 1
  typolinkCheckRootline= 0

  baseURL = {$baseURL}
  doctype = html5 
  language = de
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would prefer to use **realurl** for url-rewriting.

Realurl gives you a pretty well working default configuration and there is a good documentation & support for this extension.

[Speaking URLs for TYPO3 - typo3.org](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/realurl)

Comment: Pretty unsatisfying solution, but it works ;) But Thanks.